# Invariable colour adjectives

Tags: adjectifs, accord

> Ce vert tendre est parfait pour elle.

If the adjective tendre is removed does the sentence become:

> Cette verte est parfait pour elle?

or does it stay the same?

Comment: In this context, "vert" is a noun and not an adjective, as you can tell because of the article "Ce" that is before it. Color nouns are all masculine in french.

Answer (score 3):

Will stay the same

> Ce vert est parfait pour elle.

Answer (score 2):

You missunderstood something in your sentence.
The word "vert", the way you use it, is actually not an adjective, but a **noun**. By using the demonstrative adjetive before it, it becomes a noun. In french, this is called an **adjectif substantivé**.

I don't know the rule for the gender, but i know that the noun "vert" is masculine.
Finally,

> Cette verte

Does not exist.
But it can agree the plural case :

> Ces verts sont parfaits pour elle.

---

### Invariable colour adjectives

It is quite easy to know if you have to agree the colour adjective or not.
To agree with the noun, your colour adjective has to complete those 2 conditions :

- Not to be a derivation of a noun or any other word.
  **Noir** and **rouge** only exists as an adjective colour : they agree with a noun.
  But **orange** is also the fruit, **marron** is also a vegetable : they do not.
- To be single. **bleu** agrees with the noun, **bleu profond** and **bleu cobalt** do not.